# Parsing XML Spreadsheet in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, spreadsheet

I am trying to Parse `XML Spreadsheet`(generated using Microsoft Excel) in `Perl` and I could not find any particular module to do this.

I am able to parse XML Data file in `Perl` and that is working very well.

Can anyone please help me regarding this. A sample code or prototype would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: read this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pexcel/

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet%3a%3aXLSX) module (parsing Excel 2007 .xlsx format) with good results.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not find any particular module to do this

Where did you look? MetaCPAN lists [dozens of Excel modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=excel).